# Scrapy: Simple Project

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to start a simply scrapy project. It is a python project from visual studio. The VS is running in administration mode. 
Unfortunately, parse(...) is never called, but should..

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import logging

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['https://blog.scrapinghub.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.css('.post-header>h2'):
            yield {'title': title.css('a ::text').extract_first()}

        for next_page in response.css('div.prev-post > a'):
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
        logging.error("this should be printed")

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})
process.crawl(BlogSpider)
process.start()
print("ready")
```

EDIT: my output:

```
2018-09-22 08:23:02 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2018-09-22 08:23:02 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.5.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.7.0, Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0i  14 Aug 2018), cryptography 2.3.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
2018-09-22 08:23:02 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'}
2018-09-22 08:23:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
ready
```

As note: Twisted is used from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Anaconda, and then executed conda `install -c conda-forge scrapy` (got some errors).

Now everything works fine.

[Installation guide](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html)

Answer (score 0):

this looks entire problem of indentations once i fixed it it started working output

```
2018-09-22 11:35:47 [root] ERROR: this should be printed
```

My code snippet its same

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import logging

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['https://blog.scrapinghub.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        logging.error("this should be printed")
        for title in response.css('.post-header>h2'):
            yield {'title': title.css('a ::text').extract_first()}
        for next_page in response.css('div.prev-post > a'):
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
        logging.error("this should be printed")

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(BlogSpider)
process.start()
print("ready")
```

attaching a pastbin paste https://pastebin.com/pDu8kW27

Comment: I got that message , you want me to share my python file. I had to fix the intendtation to make it work from the code shared by you

Comment: When I ran it the first time I got logsaying can’t find blogSpear.parse